# Consultar usuário no Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Como faço para retornar ao invés de uma consulta através de um usuário fixo, o código fosse no banco consultar os usuários e retornar ele. Utilizo o Sql Server com aplicação aspnet core 3.1

Alguém que possa me ajudar nessa questão de banco?

```
public static usuario Get(string Email, string Senha)
    {
        var users = new List<usuario>();
        users.Add(new usuario { id = 1, Nome = "Cachorro", Email = "Cachorro@mail.com", Senha = "123456", Role = "manager" });
        users.Add(new usuario { id = 2, Nome = "Gato", Email = "gato@mail.com", Senha = "654321", Role = "employee" });
        return users.Where(x => x.Email.ToLower() == Email.ToLower() && x.Senha == x.Senha).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Esse código eu ja trago o usuário e senha na aplicação, mas gostaria de ele fosse buscar no banco os dados?

Comment: Amigo, pelo texto que você escreveu, sua pergunta está completamente vaga. Você quer retornar o usuário e senha? Esta usando o Identity?

Comment: @ClaudineiFerreira O sistema esta sendo criado em AspNet core 3.0. Gostaria de saber como faço a conexão com o sql server para ele consultar se o email e senha da classe usuário bate com algum do banco. Esta melhor explicado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você ter acessar o SQL SERVER defina a conexão no appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "server=mssql.servidor.com.br;user=usuario;password=senha;database=banco;Persist Security Info=True"
```

},

Cria o modelo da classe usuário na pasta Models

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string UsuarioNome {get; set;}
    public string Senha {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

Crie um contexto. Por padrão o template do visual studio cria o ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    //aqui você instancia as classes que representam o modelo da sua aplicação, no caso o usuario e senha
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios {get; set;}
}
```

E por fim na classe startup.cs, use o contexto que você criou como serviço

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Chame o gerenciador de Nuget para criar a migração que criará o banco de dados.

O primeiro comando:

```
Add-Migration Inicial -Verbose
```

Se tiver tudo certo, execute o segundo:

```
Update-Database -Verbose
```

No controller faça a Injeção de indepedencia para ter acesso a classe ligada ao banco de dados

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    } 

    public IActionResult Index()
    {

    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index(string usuario, string senha)
    {
        var result = _context.Usuarios
            .Where(x=>x.UsuarioNome == usuario)
            .Where(x=>x.Senha == senha)
            .Count() // ou .FirstOrDefault(), depende do que você queira fazer.
    }
    ...
}
```

Lembrando que essa é uma forma chula de fazer. Consulte a [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), tem tudo lá para você saber como implementar da maneira correta o que precisa e ir além.